# Three way data binding with RactiveJS and Firebase

Tags: firebase, ractivejs

I'm really wondering if there is anybody that took a shot at Firebase via RactiveJS.

What I'm confused about is that Ractive uses array modifier events to trigger some DOM changes.

So far so good, `ractive.unshift('arr',1)` would mean updating the following:

```
{{ # arr }} 
     {{ . }} 
{{ / }}
```

But.. since `Firebase` uses `Objects` instead `Arrays` how can I pull out a three-way data binding with `Ractive` ? I really enjoy the ease of use `RactiveJS` offers and I wouldn't like moving away just because of this.

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Could you update question with a small example?  Not clear why this would be a problem with set/update/computeds available.

Comment: There's no issue, I'm just trying to ask how do you do it ? I'm trying to figure out a way of getting Ractive to work with Firebase ( but I can't wrap my head around it since Firebase is using objects and Ractive listens to changes on Arrays ). Do you have any example in which you can make Ractive listen to changes from Firebase ?

Comment: Ractive `data` does not have to be an array - I don't have a Firebase example available, but briefly you'd use Firebase as normal, and when you receive a change event in Firebase, you could either: Ractive.set(...) new values based on the data, or Ractive.update(...) in addition to having computed values based on the Firebase data.

Comment: I guess I'll give it a try this way. Will come back when I find something that others could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a lot in your question, but I believe you're trying to set data. [`ractive.set`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-set) should be everything you need for that:

```
ractive.set('some.object.keypath', obj);
```

There's nothing fancy about this (there are a few under-the-hood things that happen though). This is synonymous to doing:

```
some.object.keypath = obj;
```

Also, should you want to abstract the fact that you're using Firebase, you could create an [adaptor](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/adaptors). It's essentially just an abstraction layer, translating to and from a third-party data source. A common example is adapting Backbone models to Ractive.